# Black-Scholes PDE & Terminal Condition

Tags: black-scholes, black-scholes-pde

Just a quick question I was hoping someone could shed light on.

- So far I am familiar with the Black-Scholes PDE with the terminal
  condition at time $T$ been $V(t=T,S)=(S-K)^+$.
- I also understand that the Black-Scholes PDE does not contain $S(T)$ and therefore is independent of the terminal condition.

As such, if the terminal condition was to be $(S^2 - K)^+$ the PDE for the call option remains the same - at least that is what I am told.

Intuitively I don't understand the logic behind this?

For example, if $K$ is 50 and $S$ ends up been 100;

- $(S - K) = \$50$, where as.
- $(S^2 - K) = 10,000 - 50 = \$9,950$

Surely the $(S^2 - K)+$ option must be worth a lot more?

But apparently the PDE for both these options is the same and therefore the time $t$ value is also the same?

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: Assuming $S(T)$ is the price of the stock at the terminal time $T$, then in your notation, $S=S(T)$, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct S(T) is the stock price at the terminal time T.

Comment: So the terminal condition is $(S_T - K)^+$ ... or $(S_T^2 - K)^+$ for the option on the squared price.

Comment: Wish I knew how to write the math code like you, yes ordinarily the terminal condition is as you stated.

But I have been asked to show that the PDE is the same (** and therefore I presume the option price is also the same **) for the terminal condition:

 (ST^2 - K)+

Which I believe would compare as follows at ST

For example, if K is 50 and ST ends up been 100;

(ST - K) = $50, where as.
(ST^2 - K) = 10,000 - 50 = $9,950 

So how can both options have the same t value?

Naturally I am expecting to be proven drastically wrong with my thinking here...

Comment: Yes the option prices are different.  Note that the payoff function $f(S_T)$ (e.g. $f(s) = (s^2 - K)^+$) *does* appear in the (generalised) BS PDE. Also you can write $\LaTeX$ math equations enclosed in dollar signs.

Comment: Actually, after more consideration, I retract my last comment about $f$ appearing in the PDE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDE will be the same but because the terminal condition is different the solutions will not be the same. The different boundary condition will give different values at $t=T$. Then the equation is marched backwards in time in both cases using the same equation but because the terminal condition is different the solutions will not agree

Comment: Hi aw80, thank you for your reply. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable and PDE approach is not suitable. In the Black scholes  model  we have 
$$d\ln {{S}_{T}}=\,(r-\frac{1}{2}{{\sigma }^{2}})dt+\sigma d{{W}_{t}}$$
so
$$d\ln {{S}_{T}^2}=\,(2r-{{\sigma }^{2}})dt+2\sigma d{{W}_{t}}$$
as a result
$$\ln {{S}_{T}^2}=\ln{{S}_{t}^2}\,+(2r-{{\sigma }^{2}})(T-t)+2\sigma (W_T-W_t)$$
let 
$$Y(t)=(2r-{{\sigma }^{2}})(T-t)+2\sigma [W(T)-W(t)]$$
it is clear
\begin{align}
  & \,\,\,\,{{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}}\left[ Y(t) \right]=(2r-{{\sigma }^{2}})(T-t) \\ 
 & {{\operatorname{var}}^{\mathbb{Q}}}\left[ Y(t) \right]=4{{\sigma }^{2}}(T-t) \\ 
\end{align}
in the other words we can say
$$Y\overset{d}{\mathop{=}}\,\ N\left( (2r-{{\sigma }^{2}})(T-t)\,,4{{\sigma }^{2}}\left( T-t \right) \right)$$
For simplicity we let ${\widetilde{r}}=(2r-{{\sigma }^{2}})$ and $\tau =(T-t)$ so $Y\overset{d}{\mathop{=}}\,\ N\,(\overset{\tilde{\ }}{\mathop{r}}\,\tau \,,{4{\sigma }^{2}}\tau )$ as a result

$$\frac{Y-\overset{\tilde{\ }}{\mathop{r}}\,\tau }{2\sigma \sqrt{\tau }}\overset{\,\,d}{\mathop{\,=}}\,\ N(0,\,1)$$

we have
$$\Pi (t)=e^{-{r}\tau}{{E}_{t}}^{Q}\left[ {{({{S}_{T}}^{2}-K)}^{+}} \right]=e^{-{r}\tau}{{E}_{t}}^{Q}\left[ {{({{S}_{t}}^{2}{{e}^{{{Y}_{t}}}}-K)}^{+}} \right] $$
$$\Pi (t)=e^{-{r}\tau}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{({{S}_{t}}^{2}\,{{e}^{y}}-K,\,0)}^{+}}\,{{f}_{Y}}}(y)\,dy$$
Finally we should do same procedure with $(S_T-K)^+$, then
$$\Pi (t)={{S}_{t}}{{\,}^{2}}N\left[ {{d}_{1}} \right]-K{{e}^{-r\,\tau}}\ N\left[ {{d}_{2}} \right]$$ 
where
\begin{align}
  & {{d}_{1}}=\frac{(2r+3{{\sigma }^{2}})\tau +\ln \left( \frac{{{S}_{t}}^{2}}{K} \right)}{2\sigma \sqrt{\tau }} \\ 
 & {{d}_{2}}={{d}_{1}}-2\sigma \sqrt{\tau } \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Behrouz, thank you for taking the time to reply. I can understand some of the maths here, but not all of it. What you have done at the start gives me some insight into the answer I was seeking.

I'll be saving your answer for when I can completely understand what you have done in the future.

Once again, thank you for your time.